# Client certificates on iPhone-simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The only thing I want to know is if it is possible to use client certificates on the iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  See [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Tasks for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13) in the Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Programming Guide.

If you're using a third party http library, you might have some other things to consider.  I use ASIHTTPRequest, so [here's](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#client_certificates) the certificate documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

ya you can use the client certificates on your simulator and on the device also.

just login to developer.apple.com with your client credentials and download the required certificates. attach them to your code signing identity(will be present in build settings).

you are good to go :)